# How to efficiently search on a String

Tags: java, string, search, text

I have a text with about 300 - 500 words. Also i got about 200k keywords and i want to know if each of the keywords is contained in the text. A String contains ist quite slow, is there some way to preprocess the String?

I thought about using a SuffixTree but im not sure this is the best choice.

Also, are there any good librarys for this task? semanticdiscoverytoolkit for example has a suffixtree implementation but after adding the string i cant figure out how to look up if a string is contained in the tree.

Greetings,

Nico

Comment: Are the keywords whole words, or parts of words?

Comment: whole words most of the time. the text is an abstract from pubmed, the keywords are known genes and diseases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the rabin-karp string search algorithm. since you are doing mostly hash (integer) comparisons, the performance is much better than string comparisons.

1. compute the hash of the keyword
2. compute the rolling hash of the text
3. compare these 2 hashes. if they match, perform the actual string comparison.
4. advance the position by 1 character and repeat from step 2 until you reach the end of the text.

as a analogy, the rolling hash is like a "sliding window" that scrolls along the text. the hash comparison is done using the hash of the substring in the "sliding window" against the hash of the keyword.

Comment: if i understood you right: i have the long text and a keyword and now i want to know if the keyword is contained in the long text.  I make a sliding window the length of the keyword let it scroll along the text. for every step i compute the hash of the window and the hash of the keyword and now i compare them with rabin-karp?

Comment: @Nicolas you got it. the entire 4 step process is the rabin-karp algorithm. i think rabin-karp is better than suffixtree because the running time of building the suffixtree alone is greater than the rabin-karp search algorithm. one important note: you must be able to compute the hash function within linear time and ideally, there should be minimal collisions. of course, you can try using the default string hash function and tweak it as you flesh out the details of the implementation.

Comment: @Nicolas: See these samples of Java code on Rabin-Karp: http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/425/Prog/RabinKarp.java and http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html

Comment: does any1 know of a library that implements rabin-karp search?

Comment: there's no java library for string search algorithms but you can use either one of the implementation listed by anubhava. you probably need to adapt them to suit your needs e.g. you have to pre-compute the hash of all your keywords and store them in a binary search tree for easy retrieval latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to get each of the words then populate a hashmap which you check afterwards. This requires going through each list only once. Lookup times should then be very fast which is important given the amount of keywords you have.

It may be worth it to profile this method against something like Lucene.

Comment: the problem is, with the string tokenizer method i cant find combined words which are split up to 2 words after tokenizing them